# I need JQL for MVC.Net any ideas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jql

I need to replicate the Jira JQL style advanced search in my .Net MVC project with EF.

"What is JQL style advanced search?"
http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/01/jql-the-most-flexible-way-to-search-jira-14/

I've got some ideas on how I could build this from scratch but am really hoping someone knows of an existing library/package that I can use instead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Way too broad a description of what you're looking for. Please refer to this guide and then come back and ask more specific questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is the kind of question that is considered off topic here; You might find the kind of recommendations you are looking for over at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thx Claies. Have followed your suggestion and put this question there also.

Answer (score 0):

[EasyQuery ASP.NET](http://devtools.korzh.com/easyquery/).
It's not exactly like JQL but solves the same task.

Here is an example of web-page built with EasyQuery which has quite similar functionality to the one you have in Jira while browsing issues:
http://demo.easyquerybuilder.com/data-filtering/Order